# Making a scrollable area out of a list

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a list of items that I want to fit into a widget, scroll through that widget and select each item. At first, I tried doing this with QLabels, but it just listed them as text that could not be selected with a click. Thus, I decided to go with buttons, even though its not the functionality I want.

However, it seems that there's no scroll... It just crams all elements into that area, making them very small.

What I have:

[image: scroll area with very small buttons]

What I want:

[image]

Basically I want a scroll area with all items listed such that by having one selected I can get the text contained.

My code:

```
# in class
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.monthList = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.monthList.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.monthList.setStyleSheet("background: #edb5bf")
        self.monthLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.monthList)
        Methods.ListAvailableMonths(self.monthLayout)

# in methods
def ListAvailableMonths(scrollView):
    available = os.listdir(directories)

    for month in available:
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        button.setText(month.strip())
        scrollView.addWidget(button)
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `tkinter`?

```
root = Tk() 
listbox = Listbox(root) 
listbox.pack(side = LEFT, fill = BOTH) 

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root) 
scrollbar.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = BOTH)
```

Insert the elements you want
Example here: Values 1 to 100

```
for values in range(100): 
    listbox.insert(END, values)
```

Attach Listbox to Scrollbar

```
listbox.config(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set) 
scrollbar.config(command = listbox.yview) 

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. The problem is that I am using `PyQt5` and not `tkinter` and would like to use Qt for the entire project.

Comment: Have you checked this post [link](https://www.learnpyqt.com/courses/adanced-ui-features/qscrollarea/)?

Comment: will give it a look now, thanks. Seems to be doing mostly what I need.

Comment: I managed to get the basic layout working, however its not the type of object I want. I can use a push button, however I would like a list of selectable items. What container can I use?